# Cursor Not Unlocking In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
        if (Gameplay_UI.activeInHierarchy == true && isActive == true && Loose.activeSelf == false)
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    } else
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
```

This is the code i am using to lock / unlock the cursor and it works fine for most scenarios except when the player looses (When the player looses happens the player gameObject is de activated and the loose gameObject is activated), the isActive bool is suppose to check if the player is active in the scene but like .activeself or .activeinhierachy it doesn't actually update when the player is de activated in the scene, this is the same if i check if the Loose gameobject is active,.activeself or .activeinhierachy never updates. I would love some help to unlock the cursor when the player looses, thanks.

Comment: You could unlock the cursor inside of `OnDisable`, which gets called when the object becomes disabled or inactive.

Comment: This actually worked, I'm pretty new and haven't seen that function before, Thanks alot.

Comment: Happy to help.  I will post my comment as an answer to close the question.  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can unlock the cursor inside of `OnDisable`.

[OnDisable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) gets called when the object becomes disabled or inactive.

eg.

```
private void OnDisable()
{
    UnlockCursor();
}

private void UnlockCursor()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    Cursor.visible = true;
}
```